# It's allowed to dance (and cultural events) on the Louvre Square?

Tags: paris, weddings, the-louvre

I'm travelling to Paris with some friends and I'm helping with a marriage proposal, I would like to know if the laws allow this kind of cultural event on Louvre Square or if it's forbidden, we don't want to be arrested hehe

The plan is to start dancing and after that the groom will ask her.

[image]

Comment: Notice that the regulation for Cour Napoléon : http://www.louvre.fr/sites/default/files/medias/medias_fichiers/fichiers/pdf/louvre-reglement-cours-jardins.pdf does not formally allow such project, and is almost forbiding it. (See article 8).

Comment: Hi Max - I don't have the specific answer but I'd say that ***almost certainly, you are NOT allowed to do this***.

Comment: How many people are we talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about 4 people dancing at the same time. It will bring some attention but it's not a big show or group presentation.

Answer (score 3):

France is a free country, so you can basically do as you please, and a flash mob shouldn't be an issue anywhere in a public setting.

However, if you want to stick to the letter of the law, this would probably be considered a public reunion, which may require authorisation from the "Préfecture". Also, the use of music in a public setting normally implies getting the authorisation of the rights holders and/or paying them fees. But I doubt you would have any serious issues with either of those in this specific context.

On the other hand, remember that France is under high-level alert (actually in the "Etat d'urgence" situation, which is basically just one notch below a state of war), and anything that might look suspicious may get you into trouble, especially in a high-profile "target" such as this (with lots of people and tourists), which is likely to be filled with cops and soldiers bearing arms.

I would recommend at the very least finding cops on site and notifying them of what you intend to do beforehand so they're not surprised when they see lots of people apparently preparing something.

Comment: *"France is a democracy, so you can basically do as you please"* uh what ? You may want to revisit the definition of a democracy

Comment: Indeed probably not the right formulation, though I'm not quite sure what the contrary of "authoritarian" or "totalitarian" regime would be. Looks like there is a strong correlation between democracy and freedom :-)

Comment: Democracy is a form of government, I think what you meant to say is that the French Republic guarantees certain individual rights, such as assembly.

Comment: State of emergency is worse than state of war.

Comment: "France is a democracy, so you can basically do as you please" "What in the name of goodness are you talking about?"  heh.

Comment: France operates under *code Napoleon* .. napoleonic law .. and famously is "just not like" the UK and the UK's colonies (the "USA" etc).

Comment: "Free country" might be what you want.